# I have a problem with Visual Studio 2022 where my console app doesn't show the last cases in my switches

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Sorry guys I'm new here and didn't really understood how it worked here.
So the last cases doesn't show in the console, I tried running smaller parts of the code and it works.It's af if it get's ignored for some reason and just closes the console, there are no shown errors.
Therefore my code got all scrambled, Here's a part of my code:

```
namespace langlopendetaak_Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool admin;
            string nameShop = "KickFitSupplies";
            Console.WriteLine("Hoe heet je? ");
            string nameUser = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine($"Welkom, {nameUser} bij {nameShop}! Wij verkopen de beste" +
                $" uitrustingen voor Thaiboksen en Mua-Thai \nje kan hier bokshandschoenen, Scheenbeschermers, " +
                $"kruisbeschermers, Boksbandages en Mondstukken kopen.");
            Console.ResetColor();
            string nameProduct_1 = "Bokshandschoenen";
            string nameProduct_2 = "Scheenbeschermers";
            string nameProduct_3 = "Kruisbeschermers";
            float priceProduct_1 = 59.99f;
            float priceProduct_2 = 55.49f;
            float priceProduct_3 = 25.00f;
            int quantityOfProduct_1 = 20;
            int quantityOfProduct_2 = 20;
            int quantityOfProduct_3 = 15;
            string descriptionProduct_1 = "Rode kunstleren Bokshandschoenen";
            string descriptionProduct_2 = "Zwarte kunstleren Scheenbeschermers";
            string descriptionProduct_3 = "Witte synthetisch leer Kruisbeschermers";
            string production_info_1 = "De fabrikant voor  de bokshandschoenen is Everlast";
            string production_info_2 = "De fabrikant voor  de scheenbeschermers is Everlast";
            string production_info_3 = "De fabrikant voor  de kruisbeschermers is Venum";



            Console.Write($"Product 1: {nameProduct_1} Aantal:  {quantityOfProduct_1}" +
                $"\nProduct 2: {nameProduct_2} Aantal:  {quantityOfProduct_2}" +
                $"\nProduct 3: {nameProduct_3} Aantal:  {quantityOfProduct_3}");

            Console.Write("\n1. item x bekijken\n2. item x kopen");

            int firstUserOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (firstUserOption)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Welke product wil je bekijken? ");
                    Console.WriteLine("kies uit 1, 2, 3, 4 of 5 ");
                    int optionForProducts = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Clear();
                    switch (optionForProducts)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine($"Naam van het product: {nameProduct_1} " +
                                $"Prijs(in euros)= {priceProduct_1} " +
                                $"Aantal van het product: {quantityOfProduct_1}" +
                                $"\nBeschrijving van het product: {descriptionProduct_1}" +
                                $"\nExtra info over het product: {production_info_1}");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine($"Naam van het product: {nameProduct_2} " +
                                $"Prijs(in euros)= {priceProduct_2} " +
                                $"Aantal van het product: {quantityOfProduct_2}" +
                                $"\nBeschrijving van het product: {descriptionProduct_2}" +
                                $"\nExtra info over het product: {production_info_2}");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine($"Naam van het product: {nameProduct_3} " +
                                $"Prijs(in euros)= {priceProduct_3} " +
                                $"Aantal van het product: {quantityOfProduct_3}" +
                                $"\nBeschrijving van het product: {descriptionProduct_3}" +
                                $"\nExtra info over het product: {production_info_3}");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Welk product wil je kopen? ");
                    int buyingOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("hoeveel wil je ervan kopen? ");
                    int optiequantityOfProduct = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    switch (buyingOption)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            if (optiequantityOfProduct > quantityOfProduct_1)
                            {
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, er zijn maar {quantityOfProduct_1} {nameProduct_1}" +
                                    $" in voorraad");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                            }
                            else if (optiequantityOfProduct < quantityOfProduct_1)
                            {
                                int newquantityOfProduct_1 = quantityOfProduct_1 - optiequantityOfProduct;
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Er zijn succesvol {optiequantityOfProduct} {nameProduct_1}" +
                                    $"gekocht!");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                                float totalPrice = priceProduct_1 * optiequantityOfProduct;
                                float totalPriceBTW = totalPrice + totalPrice * 0.21f;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Totale prijs= {totalPrice} Totale prijs (incl. btw) = ");
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                                Console.Write($"{totalPriceBTW}");
                                Console.ResetColor();

                            }

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (optiequantityOfProduct > quantityOfProduct_2)
                            {
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, er zijn maar {quantityOfProduct_2} {nameProduct_2}" +
                                    $" in voorraad");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                            }
                            else if (optiequantityOfProduct < quantityOfProduct_2)
                            {
                                int newquantityOfProduct_2 = quantityOfProduct_2 - optiequantityOfProduct;
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Er zijn succesvol {optiequantityOfProduct} {nameProduct_2}" +
                                    $"gekocht!");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                                float totalPrice = priceProduct_2 * optiequantityOfProduct;
                                float totalPriceBTW = totalPrice + totalPrice * 0.21f;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Totale prijs= {totalPrice} \n" +
                                    $"Totale prijs (incl. btw) = {totalPriceBTW}");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (optiequantityOfProduct > quantityOfProduct_3)
                            {
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, er zijn maar {quantityOfProduct_3} {nameProduct_3}" +
                                    $" in voorraad");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                            }
                            else if (optiequantityOfProduct < quantityOfProduct_3)
                            {
                                int newquantityOfProduct_3 = quantityOfProduct_3 - optiequantityOfProduct;
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Er zijn succesvol {optiequantityOfProduct} {nameProduct_3}" +
                                    $"gekocht!");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                                float totalPrice = priceProduct_3 * optiequantityOfProduct;
                                float totalPriceBTW = totalPrice + totalPrice * 0.21f;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Totale prijs= {totalPrice} \n" +
                                    $"Totale prijs (incl. btw) = {totalPriceBTW}");
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to trim my code while doing so I messed it up, because stack has this code fences that I didn't knew  about. Again sorry for the trouble I hope this is better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I will try to debug and see if I can spot the problem, thx for the advise!

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.. I can help but please paste the code so that it compiles without errors..

Comment: I don't understand your code at all.  You are asking for options 1-5 but only check for blocks 1-2 or 4-5.  You also have random `break;` lines everywhere.

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, you might have enabled a setting in Visual Studio where Visual Studio uses your last compilable code rather than what you have currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One break statement is illegal:

```cs
switch (optionForProducts) {
    // break; <======== REMOVE THIS break!
    case 4:
```

You can also use raw string literals to simplify the code:

```cs
switch (optionForProducts) {
    // break; <======== REMOVE THIS break!
    case 4:
        Console.WriteLine($"""
            Naam van het product: {nameProduct_4} Prijs(in euros)= {priceProduct_4} Aantal van het product: {quantityOfProduct_4}
            Beschrijving van het product: {descriptionProduct_4}
            Extra info over het product: {production_info_4}
            """);
        break;
    case 5:
        Console.WriteLine($"""
            Naam van het product: {nameProduct_5} Prijs(in euros)= {priceProduct_5} Aantal van het product: {quantityOfProduct_5}
            Beschrijving van het product: {descriptionProduct_5}
            Extra info over het product: {production_info_5}
            """);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Ongeldige keuzen");
        break;
}
break;
```

You are repeating exactly the same code with different variables. Also these variables are numbered and the switch statement switches by this very number. If you instead used arrays, no switch and no repetition would be required.

With these declarations:

```cs
int[] quantityOfProduct, newquantityOfProduct;
string[] nameProduct, descriptionProduct, production_info;
float[] priceProduct;
```

The switch becomes:

```cs
switch (firstUserOption) {
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Welke product wil je bekijken? ");
        Console.WriteLine("kies uit 1, 2, 3, 4 of 5 ");
        int optionForProducts = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
        switch (optionForProducts) {
            case 4 or 5:
                int i = optionForProducts - 1;
                Console.WriteLine($"""
                    Naam van het product: {nameProduct[i]} Prijs(in euros)= {priceProduct[i]} Aantal van het product: {quantityOfProduct[i]}
                    Beschrijving van het product: {descriptionProduct[i]}
                    Extra info over het product: {production_info[i]}
                    """);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Ongeldige keuze");
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Welk product wil je kopen? ");
        int buyingOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("hoeveel wil je ervan kopen? ");
        int optiequantityOfProduct = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (buyingOption is >= 1 and <= 5) {
            int i = buyingOption - 1;
            if (optiequantityOfProduct > quantityOfProduct[i]) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, er zijn maar {quantityOfProduct[i]} {nameProduct[i]} in voorraad");
                Console.ResetColor();
            } else if (optiequantityOfProduct < quantityOfProduct[i]) {
                newquantityOfProduct[i] = quantityOfProduct[i] - optiequantityOfProduct;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine($"Er zijn succesvol {optiequantityOfProduct} {nameProduct[i]} gekocht!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                float totalPrice = priceProduct[i] * optiequantityOfProduct;
                float totalPriceBTW = totalPrice + totalPrice * 0.21f;
                Console.WriteLine($"Totale prijs= {totalPrice} Totale prijs (incl. btw) = ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write($"{totalPriceBTW}");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
        break;
}
```

Note: Array indexes are 0-based. Therefore a the index is option - 1.

---

You have edited your question after I have posted the first part of my answer, which partly invalidates it.

You could initialize the arrays like this (from edited code):

```cs
string[] nameProduct = { "Bokshandschoenen", "Scheenbeschermers", "Kruisbeschermers"};
decimal[] priceProduct = { 59.99m, 55.49m, 25.00m };
int[] quantityOfProduct = { 20, 20, 15 };
string[] descriptionProduct = { 
    "Rode kunstleren Bokshandschoenen", 
    "Zwarte kunstleren Scheenbeschermers",
    "Witte synthetisch leer Kruisbeschermers" };
string[] production_info ={
    "De fabrikant voor  de bokshandschoenen is Everlast",
    "De fabrikant voor  de scheenbeschermers is Everlast",
    "De fabrikant voor  de kruisbeschermers is Venum" };
int[] newquantityOfProduct = new int[nameProduct.Length];
```

Also, you should use the `decimal` type for prices. `float` and `double` tend to produce values like `2.9999999`.

Now that we have arrays, we can also simplify writing the product list:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < nameProduct.Length; i++) {
    Console.Write($"Product {i + 1}: {nameProduct[i]} Aantal: {quantityOfProduct[i]}");
}
```

The advantage of arrays and loops is that the code stays the same no matter how many products you have.

---

Things become easier if you regroup the different product attributes into a single class:

```cs
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need only one variable for all the products and their attributes. It also makes sense to use a `List<T>` instead of an array. Arrays have a fixed size while list can grow or shrink.

```cs
List<Product> products = new() {
    new() {
        Name = "Bokshandschoenen",
        Description = "Rode kunstleren Bokshandschoenen",
        Info = "De fabrikant voor  de bokshandschoenen is Everlast",
        Price = 59.99m,
        Quantity = 20 },
    new() {
        Name = "Scheenbeschermers",
        Description = "Zwarte kunstleren Scheenbeschermers",
        Info = "De fabrikant voor  de scheenbeschermers is Everlast",
        Price = 55.49m,
        Quantity = 20 },
    new() {
        Name = "Kruisbeschermers",
        Description = "Witte synthetisch leer Kruisbeschermers",
        Info = "De fabrikant voor  de kruisbeschermers is Venum",
        Price = 25.00m,
        Quantity = 15 },
};
```

Writing the product list becomes:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++) {
    Console.Write($"Product {i + 1}: {products[i].Name} Aantal: {products[i].Quantity}");
}
```

Comment: I think the format problem is caused by the extra quote after `{production_info[i]}`; Also the text "Ongeldige keuzen" must be "Ongeldige keuze"

Comment: Nice catch for the extra `"`. I am not going to fix a dutch  text since I don't speek it.

Comment: It is my native language :D